# Is there exists language such that its first (second) half is NP-complete (P), but whole world is NP-COMPLETE (P)

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, np-complete

> Let $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$,
>   $$
> \frac12 L=\{w \in \Sigma^* \mid \exists v \in \Sigma^*\  wv\in L \text{ and }|w|=|v|\}
> $$
>   $$ L\frac12=\{w\in \Sigma^* \mid  \exists v\in \Sigma^*\  vw\in L\text{ and }|w|=|v|\}$$ 
>   (1) Is
>   there exists language $L$ such that $L\in P$, but $\frac12L, L\frac12
>  $  are $NP$-complete ?
>   (2) Is there exists language $L$ such that $L$
>   is $NP$-complete, but $\frac12 L, L\frac12$ are in $P$ ?

I don't know what I should think about it.  I have no idea how to solve it. Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 1):

1. **The language of puzzles and their answer key**. This problem reminds me of the fact that NP problems are "hard to solve but easy to verify". When you have a solution to any NP problem, you can check it in polynomial time.

   So, pick an NP-complete language such as HAMPATH "The set of all directed graphs that have Hamiltonian paths".  Define $L$ to be the language of all strings where the first half is a problem in HAMPATH and the second half is a solution to the problem. (Add filler symbols to make sure the two halves have the same length.)

   Now, $L$ is in $P$ because the solution to an NP-complete problem can be checked in polynomial time.  But $\frac{1}{2}L$ is NP-complete because HAMPATH is an NP-complete language.
2. **The language of puzzle-pairs that contain each other's solutions**. Making sure that *both* halves of the language are NP-complete is a little trickier, but doable. The idea is to make a language of strings $P_1xP_2y$ where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are NP hard problems,  $x$ and $y$ together give a solution key for $P_1$ and $P_2$, but when separated $x$ and $y$ give no useful information. Then you can quickly confirm $P_1xP_2y$ (the language is in P), but $P_1x$ and $P_2y$ are just hard problems (both in NP-complete).

   Let $L$ be the language of all strings with the following properties: The first half is a graph $G$ in HAMPATH and an isomorphism $G\rightarrow H$. The second half is a graph $H$ in HAMPATH and a Hamiltonian path in $G$.

   If you know $G$, $H$ , an isomorphism $G\rightarrow H$, and a Hamiltonian path in $G$, you can easily confirm whether $G$ and $H$ are in HAMPATH in polynomial time. Hence $L$ is in P.

   If you only know the first half of a string in $L$, however, you only have a graph $G$ and an isomorphism with another (unknown) graph. Deciding whether $G$ is in HAMPATH is an NP-complete problem, hence $\frac{1}{2}L$ is NP-complete.  If you only know the second half of a string in $L$, then you have a graph $H$ and a Hamiltonian path for a *different (unknown) graph* $G$. Without knowing the isomorphism $G\rightarrow H$, I argue knowing this Hamiltonian path doesn't help you decide whether $H$ is in HAMPATH. Hence $L\frac{1}{2}$ is NP complete.
3. **The language of simple strings combined with a complicated rule**. To make both halves easy (in P) but the combined string hard (NP complete), the idea is to find a language consisting of pairs of objects, where each object is separately not too special (you can decide whether it's well-formed in polynomial time), but the rule for pairing them up is complicated and deciding whether the pairing is valid is NP-complete.  Hence the language of whole strings will be NP-complete even if the halves are both in P.

   The SUBGRAPH-ISO problem is: Given two graphs $G$ and $H$, is $G$ isomorphic to a *subgraph* of $H$? This problem is NP-complete.  Therefore, let $L$ be the set of strings where the first half is a graph $G$ and the second half is a graph $H$ containing a subgraph isomorphic to $G$. (Pad the strings as necessary so that both halves have the same length.)

   Then $L$ is NP-complete, but the first and second halves of $L$ are just the set of all strings corresponding to valid graphs. That's decideable in P.